# Doing another task while copying a directory

Tags: command-line, server, 17.10, copy

Am on Server 17.10 and am copying a directory that is some 500Gb in size, so is there a way to  continue doing something else while the directory copies?? The transfer has already been started and there is no progress report, only the cursor blinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the command in the background by appending the `&` symbol to the command line:

```
cp source_directory target_directory &
```

You can query current background tasks with the 'jobs' command.

If you forget to use the `&` in the initial command it is possible to pause it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, then move the command to the background by typing `bg` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.